# Moderator messages render tags in preview, but not when sent

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderator-messages

I recently sent a moderator message that had tags in it:

[foo-bar](/questions/tagged/foo-bar)

The tag showed up correctly in the preview (much like it does here), but did not show up in the rendered message once I clicked 'send'.

Possible solutions:
 1. Implement it for the rendered message
 2. strip out `[tag: ]` from messages or warn moderators not to send messages with this content.

Comment: I'm sort of on board with this, but keep in mind that even if we support formatting on the site, the email copy would still look weird.

Comment: @AdamLear Yea; that's what I figured when I saw that it was rendered weirdly.  In those cases it could be stripped out (or ignored), but I realize that *any* solution would take work, and is probably low priority.

Comment: If we're going to do this, I'd argue against stripping anything out for the email. At least, I know when I use the `[tag:]` syntax, I tend to write my sentences with that in mind, so if it suddenly wasn't there, my grammar would look odd at best. (More so than it already does. :))

Comment: I'd be in favor for not distributing it, but like Adam, I'm very hedgy about automatic stripping. Even for something as so obviously-going-to-be-only-this-kind-of-scenario as `[tag: ]`

Comment: @AdamLear Great points, hadn't thought about the implications for stripping it.

Comment: They could show the tags the way Careers does it-- simple text on light blue background. This doesn't break in GMail, at any rate. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ijGHk.png